# How do I make the search in the typeahead widget more efficient

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have a typeahead widget to get the state or city's population according to what the user types

Instead of issuing a GET request every time the user is done typing, the way this typeahead widget works is fetch data beforehand and store it in memory and every time user types, we are iterating through the data to retrieve the stuff that we need.

The live demo is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/saveddatatypeahead-lcyfg?file=/src/index.js

So the data is fetched like this

```js
const data = [];

fetch(endpoint)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => {
    data.push(...result);
  });
```

and we listen for the `input` event on the input field, the `timeId` is for debouncing the searching, we don't want to search too frequently

```js
searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if (e.target.value.length > 2) {
    if (timeId) {
      clearTimeout(timeId);
    }
    timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      displayMatches(e.target.value);
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

and the search is performed here

```js
function findMatches(regex, data) {
  // the time complexity is 
  // O(M x K)
  // M is the length of a city or state
  // K is the keyword to match
  // e.g. M - 'New York' K - 'yo'
  return data.filter(
    place => place.city.match(regex) || place.state.match(regex)
  );
}
```

Here the regex is constructed based on what the user typed `const regex = new RegExp(text, "ig");`

So for now it seems to me that the time complexity for the searching here is  `O(N x M x K)`
`N` is the number of entries in the `data` array, `M` is the average length of every city or state's name, and `K` is the keyword the user typed.

So my question is, **is there a way to make the search more efficient?** For now I have done two things to improve the efficiency.

1.if what the user types is less than 3 characters, we don't perform the search

2.debounce the search and only fire it when the user is done typing

Right the amount of data is not huge but I can see that it doesn't scale well with this naive implementation of search. Maybe building a trie can help? I am not sure.

Also any other suggestions and critiques about this widget are highly welcomed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for advice on refactoring working code to be more efficient, thus it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Taplar wait I am not asking for refactoring! I am asking if I analyzed the time complexity right and ways to get it better.

Comment: "and ways to get it better".  That's refactoring.

Comment: @Taplar can you not close it? I have posted on codereview.stackexchange.com  and there are not many people willing to answer questions related to front end development compare to SO.

Comment: I do not have the javascript gold badge that would allow me to close it immediately.  However, as the author you should have the ability to delete the question, in the lower left of the question.

Comment: @Taplar glad you didn't have it to close it immediately.

Comment: In your sample you have 1000 city, I doubt this is slow? A more restrictive approach is to avoid the regex and simply match by starting string (e.g typing york will not yield new york). Such approach would allow you to build a trie but for 1000 city it is not that pertinent. You should ask a very concrete problem, stated as is, doing "better" is no more than subjective @Joji

Comment: @grodzi it doesn't matter how many "cities" I have for now. The problem is about how to scale with the search. Right now with this time complexity I doubt it will scale well. I don't know how I can make this problem more "concrete" I have the code, and the data, and a very explicitly said the time complexity of the search functionality is the main concern. Why do you think it is still not concrete enough?

Comment: Your pb is too broad. If e.g you restrict it to: I have an array of strings, for a given str s, I want to find strings of the array in minimal time then this becomes easier to answer. If you add the restriction: The string of the array which __start__ by given string, this becomes even more narrower and so forth. Debouncing and such are useful methods to ui but you are not asking some ui tricks right ?